# Realm object does not update, after adding objects in it

Tags: android, database, sql-update, realm, realm-list

Can somebody explain this to me?
This is my code, and after, I'm going to show the logs. The fact is that I have a list of objects. I log it's size: 1. I clear it, becomes 0. I add objects in it, and it's still 0.

This is my code:

```
 Log.i("", "update step pitstop 1 BEFORE TEST FOR ACTIVE -> ACTIVE" + index);
                    RealmList<TripStep> tripsteps = psTrip.getTripSteps();
                    Log.i("", "update step pitstop 1 BEFORE TEST FOR ACTIVE -> ACTIVE2:" + psTrip.getTripSteps().size());
                    realmActive.beginTransaction();
                    TripStep tripStep = realmActive.copyToRealmOrUpdate(updateStepResponse.getStep());
                    realmActive.commitTransaction();
                    Log.i("", "update step pitstop 1 BEFORE TEST FOR ACTIVE -> ACTIVE3 + index is:" + index);
                    realmActive.beginTransaction();
                    tripsteps.set(index, tripStep);
                    realmActive.commitTransaction();
                    Log.i("", "update step pitstop 1 BEFORE TEST FOR ACTIVE -> ACTIVE4");
                    if (isRoaming) {
                        if ((tripsteps.size() - 2 == index) && !Utils.hasStarted(PSNewJourneyActivity.this)) {
                            realmActive.beginTransaction();
                            tripsteps.get(tripsteps.size() - 1).setTravelMode(updateStepResponse.getStep().getTravelMode());
                            realmActive.commitTransaction();
                        }
                    }
                    Log.i("", "update step pitstop 1 BEFORE TEST FOR ACTIVE -> ACTIVE5 tripsteps not in pstrip:" + tripSteps.size());
                    Log.i("", "update step pitstop 1 BEFORE TEST FOR ACTIVE -> ACTIVE5 tripsteps not in pstrip before:" + psTrip.getTripSteps().size());
                    realmActive.beginTransaction();
                    psTrip.getTripSteps().clear();
                    realmActive.commitTransaction();
                    Log.i("", "update step pitstop 1 BEFORE TEST FOR ACTIVE -> ACTIVE5 tripsteps not in pstrip AFTER CLEAR:" + psTrip.getTripSteps().size());
                    realmActive.beginTransaction();
                    for (TripStep tripStep1 : tripsteps){
                        psTrip.getTripSteps().add(tripStep1);
                    }
                    realmActive.commitTransaction();
                    realmActive.beginTransaction();
                    realmActive.copyToRealmOrUpdate(psTrip);
                    realmActive.commitTransaction();
                    Log.i("", "update step pitstop 1 BEFORE TEST FOR ACTIVE -> ACTIVE6 tripstep size:" + psTrip.getTripSteps().size());
                    Handler han = new Handler();
                    han.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            continueInit(true, true);
                            ProgressForMap(true);
                        }
                    }, mapDelay);
```

This is my log:

```
update step pitstop 1 BEFORE TEST FOR ACTIVE -> ACTIVE0
09-09 10:12:11.219  32740-32740/nl.hgrams.passenger I/﹕ update step pitstop 1 BEFORE TEST FOR ACTIVE -> ACTIVE2:1
09-09 10:12:11.251  32740-32740/nl.hgrams.passenger I/﹕ update step pitstop 1 BEFORE TEST FOR ACTIVE -> ACTIVE3 + index is:0
09-09 10:12:11.257  32740-32740/nl.hgrams.passenger I/﹕ update step pitstop 1 BEFORE TEST FOR ACTIVE -> ACTIVE4
09-09 10:12:11.257  32740-32740/nl.hgrams.passenger I/﹕ update step pitstop 1 BEFORE TEST FOR ACTIVE -> ACTIVE5 tripsteps not in pstrip:1
09-09 10:12:11.257  32740-32740/nl.hgrams.passenger I/﹕ update step pitstop 1 BEFORE TEST FOR ACTIVE -> ACTIVE5 tripsteps not in pstrip before:1
09-09 10:12:11.264  32740-32740/nl.hgrams.passenger I/﹕ update step pitstop 1 BEFORE TEST FOR ACTIVE -> ACTIVE5 tripsteps not in pstrip AFTER CLEAR:0
09-09 10:12:11.277  32740-32740/nl.hgrams.passenger I/﹕ update step pitstop 1 BEFORE TEST FOR ACTIVE -> ACTIVE6 tripstep size:0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little puzzling. One thing I would say is this:

```
                    // this part makes sense
                    realmActive.beginTransaction(); 
                    for (TripStep tripStep1 : tripsteps){
                        psTrip.getTripSteps().add(tripStep1);
                    }
                    realmActive.commitTransaction();

                    // why are you then doing this?
                    //realmActive.beginTransaction();
                    //realmActive.copyToRealmOrUpdate(psTrip);
                    //realmActive.commitTransaction();
```

As far as I can tell, the first part alone should be enough, the second part is doing nothing.

UPDATE:

Just noticed that your variable `tripsteps` is assigned here:

```
RealmList<TripStep> tripsteps = psTrip.getTripSteps();
```

and then later on you do this:

```
psTrip.getTripSteps().clear();
```

`tripsteps` and `psTrip.getTripSteps()` are pointing to the same object so when you call `psTrip.getTripSteps().clear();` you are also clearing `tripsteps`.

So at this point there will nothing in `tripsteps`:

```
for (TripStep tripStep1 : tripsteps){ // tripsteps.size() == 0
    psTrip.getTripSteps().add(tripStep1);
}
```

I think you need to "deep copy" your arraylist:

This is wrong:

```
RealmList<TripStep> tripsteps = psTrip.getTripSteps();
```

Do this instead:

```
RealmList<TripStep> tripsteps = cloneList(psTrip.getTripSteps());

public List<TripStep> cloneList(RealmList<TripStep> list) {
    List<TripStep> clone = new ArrayList<TripStep>(list.size());
    for(TripStep item : list){
        clone.add(new TripStep(item));
    }

    return clone;
}
```

You'll need to create a constructor in your `TripStep` class that can copy form another instance:

```
class TripStep
{
    public TripStep()
    { ... } // Regular constructor

    public TripStep(TripStep cloneFrom) {
        // Copy all the fields of TripStep.
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to take it out. It was a desperate move, to try to see if it helps in any way. But this is not working, it will be 0.

Comment: It works with the second added. will set as Solved, thanks a lot!